# swing and javafx support on linux

Tags: java, linux, swing, javafx-2

I have created a project on java swing using `javafx` controls as well.
Now I m trying to run my project on `Linux` but its showing unsupported class version that I understood. Now I am trying to compile the class files then its showing a lot of errors even 
its not supporting to java swing classes . I have installed `jre1.7.0` on my Linux user
directory. should I install any other java version also. A simple program for just 
printing on the screen is running smoothly.

Comment: first are you sure X11 display system is installed with your linux?

Comment: x11 display system ? i m not aware about it

Comment: i m now compiling the program in jdk1.7.0 for linux.

Comment: try running gdm or kdm or do you have any desktop manager which you can use on your linux system?

Comment: ya these commands are working

Comment: update the question with Stacktrace now, Will have to dig deep I guess.

Comment: Are you certain JRE1.7.0 is high enough ? I vaguely remember you need JDK1.7.06 or higher for JavaFX

Comment: @Robin I use 1.7.O,works fine

Comment: @user1868052 are you using some IDE?

Comment: @joeyrohan I thought for Linux and OS X JavaFX was only included in the default JRE as of that version, and for Windows it was already included in 1.7.0 (I should have been more specific)

Comment: @Robin try JavaFX 2 and see if it works.