# run javafx and swing jar on linux

Tags: java, linux, javafx

I want to know whether linux supports java swing with javafx or it does not. If yes then how can i run the jar file created from  windows jdk.
Can i run the setup on linux like windows? Should I compile the java files in linux java compiler. When i tried to compile them its giving a lot errors.

Comment: possible duplicate of [swing and javafx support on linux](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14020939/swing-and-javafx-support-on-linux)

Comment: plus 10 points from Azzy to yu just to finish your century :)

Comment: @Azzy: Upvotes are meant for something else than crossing 100/1000/10000.

Comment: @Ajinkya: just to give a moral support :)

And anyhow, I thought the question is useful too atleast for the beginner user who is still learning to combine Java and Linux

Comment: @Azzy: Second reason sounds good. Also this question seems to be duplicate and likely to get closed soon.